# Returning closure from a closure as return value for function

Tags: rust, closures, traits

I'm trying to get used to `impl Fn`, but I don't understand the error for this code:

```
fn y(state: bool) -> impl Fn() -> impl Fn(bool) -> bool {
    move || {
        println!("state, {}", state);
        |x: bool| {
            println!("state, {}", state);
            !x
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    y(true)()(true);
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
 --> src/main.rs:1:35
  |
1 | fn y(state: bool) -> impl Fn() -> impl Fn(bool) -> bool {
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. Why is it allowed for the first `impl Fn`, but not allowed for the second?
2. How this can be done without using the heap (via `Box`, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the message closer, it explains exactly what the issue is:

> ```
> `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
> ```

At the moment, you can only use `impl Trait`:

- As the return type of a function: `fn` used outside of an `impl` block.
- As the return type of an inherent method: `fn` used in an `impl Type` block.

And that's it.

Therefore, you cannot form a trait `Fn() -> impl X`.

I would note that this is, hopefully, a temporary limitation as work is ongoing to extend the places where `impl X` can be used, and associated types and trait methods are desired.

> Why is it allowed for the first `impl Fn`, but not allowed for the second?

The first `impl Fn` is the return type of a function (`y`) so it is allowed. The second is the return type of a trait method so it is not.

> How this can be done without using the heap?

You could return a concrete instance out of the first `Fn`.

For example, if you do not need state, you could return a `fn(bool) -> bool` instead.

Otherwise, you would need to manually create a struct which encapsulates said state so as to be able to name the type, instead of relying on a closure.